# Table inside a fcolorbox

Tags: tables

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am trying to create an environment similar to a colored `textbox`in MS Word and enter text, table, and formulas inside the box. Right now, this is what I do:

```
  \fcolorbox{black}{black!20}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \color{red!70!black}%
text text math math
    }}
```

However, when I try to include a table inside this environment, I get error. Is it possible to modify this environment such that it can also accommodate the tables as well?

Here is a `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
text $i=j$ 


      \fcolorbox{black}{black!20}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \color{red!50!black}%
again text and $math$
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}

      \textbf{Q} & \textbf{test}&\textbf{test2}\\
      \hline
      5 &&\\
      \hline
      \end{tabular}%

\end{table}
        }}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem here with the inclusion of a `tabular`. Yes, a `tabular`, not a `table`. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that clearly shows your problem.

Comment: @Werner: I updated my question to include a MWE. Is it possible to accommodate table environment somehow? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot embed (or contain) a float inside a box (`\parbox` or `minipage`, say). Moreover, you don't need the `table` (float) environment in order to set a `tabular`. So you could just get by with the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,tabularx}
\begin{document}
text $i=j$ 

\noindent
\fcolorbox{black}{black!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
  \color{red!50!black}%
  again text and $math$
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \textbf{Q} & \textbf{test}&\textbf{test2}\\
      \hline
      5 &&\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}}
\end{document}
```

Note that using a `\parbox` of width `\textwidth` inside a `\fcolorbox` will cause an overfull `\hbox`. That is because the `\fcolorbox` adds some separation (`\fboxsep` on both sides) and a rule (of width `\fboxrule`, on both sides). I've accommodated for this using

```
\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule
```

as the width of the `\parbox`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the package `xcolor`.  As best I can tell from the snippet of code you provided, you haven't loaded this package.  Otherwise, you example should work fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{black!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
First & Second & Third \\
A  & B & C \\
1 & 2 & 3 
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}}


\end{document}
```

[image]